# Frequent 'out of shared memory' exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm maintaining a Django app that CRUDs data on a Postgres DB.

I frequently get

```
ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

messages from time to time ... especially when i try to run some adhoc jobs.

This is basically what my function (decorated as a Celery task) looks like:

```
@app.task()
def myfunc(params):
    LOGGER.info("Starting func.")

    col1, col2, col3 = transformer(params)

    count_new_records = 0
    with transaction.atomic():
        for item in my_iterable:
            template_obj, created = MyTable.objects.get_or_create(
                col1=col1,
                defaults={
                    'col2': col2,
                    'col3': col3
                }
            )
            if not created:
                template_obj.col3 = template_obj.col3 + col3
                template_obj.save()
            else:
                count_new_records += 1
    
    LOGGER.info(str(count_new_records) + " new records created.")
    LOGGER.info("Ending func.")
```

Is there an issue with my code that causes the errors? Maybe locks not getting released correctly? If so, how can I resolve this issue & avoid having to increase `max_locks_per_transaction` every time?

Comment: Please show the resulting SQL statement.

Comment: I don't think we can tell anything from that.  Is that thing you show the adhoc job, or is that the, uh, non-adhoc job?  Why would you need to keep increasing max_locks_per_transaction?  Increase it in the config file.  It does not wear off.  Are you using partitioned tables?

Comment: I only received this error for a certain table - it is partitioned, yes, at a daily level. I was getting the error even with a simple `select * from mytable limit 10;`. 
I increased `max_locks_per_transaction` to `248` in the config. That didn't work. Then I increased `work_mem` to 32MB and now it's working fine.
But what is the RCA? Am I not releasing locks correctly? This issue keeps cropping up from time to time.